# How to automatically insert rows based on a cell's value?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps

So I'm basically trying to insert an amount of rows that is equal to a cell's number value "C12:D12" + 12 extra rows to the top and 3 extra rows to the bottom. I want the rows that are going to be added to be the same as the other ones (conditional formatting, formulas etc.), starting from E13:L13 (without the values, only the row) and going under E13:L13 (Like E14:L14 and so on). To summarize, I want the amount of cells that C12:D12 has as number value + 15.

I've tried several scripts but none of them seemed to be working, I think it is because I have a template (extra rows and stuff). I have taken a look at some of the questions, but the answer is still a no.

Edit: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/113ejYdAGcCw0eX4Liyu1nL1kkZdsmOL3dY2h3xfs5KE/edit?usp=sharing
for the sheet. Apologies, couldn't think of it earlier.
In the most simple way, I'm looking for a way that I can keep the amount of rows in that sheet equal to the C12:D12 (=COUNTA(E13:E86)) + 12 for the top area and 3 for the bottom.
Once again, I apologize as I could not think of a better explanation.

Comment: I could use an explanation that goes along with an image.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please show what you tried, add some sample data and the expected result using tables to show the cell content, and add more details about the posts from this site that you reviewed like links and a summary of the most relevant of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?
according to your sample sheet, this function add a row to A86:R86, which maintains all formats of A86:R86.

```
function insertRows() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName('In Training');
  sheet.getRange(86,1,1,16).insertCells(SpreadsheetApp.Dimension.ROWS);
}
```